# Is Core Dump harmful?

Tags: command-line, memory-usage

When in irb, pry, or an infinite loop in the terminal, I use core dump to exit becuase Ctrl - D doesn't always work and Ctrl - C never works (my Ctrl - C seems to be broken). Is Core Dump harmful in anyway?

Comment: I'm honestly more concerned that your ^C doesn't work.

Comment: Me too. I posted a separate post about this.